# Multiple View Controllers cause Memory Pressure

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an **iOS application** and I'm having trouble figuring out how to push a single `ViewController` multiple times.

To be more clear let's say I have a VC called A that is the receiver of some event. When A intercept the event he push to B (another `ViewController`). Now here it comes the problem. when A receive another message, he try to push a C `viewController` on top of A. But after a couple of times I have a crash caused by **Memory Pressure**. Is there a simple way to create some mechanism like this?

Comment: How you deal with this depends on what you want. When a new event comes in, and the app is in B, what would you like to see? Do you want to replace the content of B with whatever you need to respond to this new event? Do you want, instead, to append the new data, so you can see both? You need to give us some more detail about your app.

Comment: I need to replace the content of B so in generally I maybe don't need to instantiate another VC but when I use the Built-in back button I need to see the previous VC. Like this A-> push B -> push C now I'm in C and when I press the Back Button I want to show content of B. I can do something like this without insatiate a ViewController every time?

Comment: That's fine, you can still do that. When A receives a new event, just replace the content in B -- VCA already created a reference to B when it initially did the push. It can update some property in B, and B can detect that update by overriding the setter for that property.

Comment: So when I press back button from B I'm suppose to go to the previous content of B (if there is one) not A, is it correct?

Comment: If you only have one VCB (and you're switching out its content), then pressing the back button will take you to VCA. If you want to see the previous content of VCB, then you have to use some other way to do that -- the back button is for going back to the previous controller.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to rethink your navigational model. You mention pushing view controllers, which leads me to believe that you are using a `UINavigationController`. Pushing a new view controller instance every time will certainly cause memory issues.

It sounds like you might be better off with a tab bar navigation, or something custom that will swap out your view controllers' views rather than creating additional view controllers.